# How to use a PHP variable as an iframe src?

Tags: php, html, variables, iframe

I have scoured google with this question and read through many articles, tutorials, PHP guides and other peoples questions. But not a single solution has worked for me so far. I know it must be something simple.

This is my code:

```html
<?php
$random=array_rand("http://www.mentor-distribution.com/media/gmaster_header.mp4", "http://www.mentor-distribution.com/media/hs_freedom_chair.mp4");
?>


<html>
<body>
<iframe width="320" height="187" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($random); ?>"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is how it appears on inspect element:
[Chrome's inspect element output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9875.jpg)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array_rand` call is wrong. Use:

```
<?php
$array = [
    "http://www.mentor-distribution.com/media/gmaster_header.mp4",
    "http://www.mentor-distribution.com/media/hs_freedom_chair.mp4"
];
$randomIndex = array_rand($array);
$random = $array[$randomIndex];
?>
```

The documentation (http://php.net/array_rand) states that the first argument of `array_rand` should be an array. You provided a string.

When in doubt, be paranoid. Check if every variable has the value you expect it to have, using `var_dump` for instance. In this case you would have discovered that `$random` wasn't set to a valid url.

One final note is that I would refrain from using `<iframe>`s as video players. Look into the HTML5 `<video>` element, as explained on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Thanks for the near instant reply. the iframe is now loading but the iframe src is now displaying as either a 0 or a 1 when loaded and not one of the url's. which means it returns a 404 error inside the iframe.

Comment: You are right. `array_rand` returns a random index. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i would love to use <video> tags but i can use the as something on our Magento store blocks them, the store was setup before i began working here so i dont know why it happens.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted for future reference :)